# Using pop-up for information about errors

Tags: javascript, php, forms, popup

I have PHP form like this:

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $name       = (string) $_POST['name'];
    $email      = (string) $_POST['email'];
    $message    = (string) $_POST['message'];
    $number     = (string) $_POST['number'];
    $tel        = (string) $_POST['tel'];
    $model      = implode(',', $_POST['model_list']);
    $captcha    = (string) $_POST['captcha'];

    $from       = 'abc@domain.tld';
    $to         = 'cba@domain.tld';
    $subject    = 'Form service';

    $body = "$name \n $email \n $tel \n $number \n $model \n $message \n";    

    try {    
        if (!$name) {    
            throw new Exception('Error 1');    
        }

        if (!$email || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {    
            throw new Exception('Error 2');    
        }

        if($captcha > 10) {
        } elseif ($captcha < 1) {
            throw new Exception('Error 3');
        }

        if(!$number) {
            throw new Exception('Error 4');
        }

        if(!$number) {
            throw new Exception('Error 5');
        }    

        if (!$message) {    
            throw new Exception('Error 6');    
        }

        if(!empty($_POST['model_list'])) {
            foreach($_POST['model_list'] as $model) {
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Error 7');
        }

        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from, $captcha, $model)) {    
            $result = "Your message has been sent!";    
        } else {    
            throw new Exception('Your message has not been sent! Try again.');    
        }    

    } catch(Exception $e){    
        $result = "<center><div style='color:white;font-size:25px;font-weight:700;'>" . $e->getMessage() . "</div></center>";    
    }

    echo $result;    
}
```

I would like to use pop up to show information about errors or result if message were sent, and I don't know how to make it correct. Is it needed to use JavaScript? Or it could be done only in PHP (I would prefer it because I have never learnt JS).

Regards.

Comment: look at syntax highlighting; you have errors and this is the part that is throwing if off `$body = [here is what is sent by email]`

Comment: `throw new Exception('Error 4)` that now is throwing it off `throw new Exception('Error 4')` - Please, if you are using proper code, you should post it. Others may think that your code is failing because of it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had to edit this places because this errors are in different language and I wouldn't edited all of it.

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, you will need to use JS in order to have a popup. PHP doesn't handle that type of thing.

Comment: So it's one problem I wrote about. I have never learnt JS and don't understand anything from it and I don't know anybody who knows.

Comment: Here's a very basic example; http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert

Comment: It's not perfectly what I want, but thank you a lot.